# Why are soaked dried soy beans cooked before fermenting?

Tags: food-safety, fermentation, beans, tofu, soybeans

Is it necessary to cook soaked dried soy beans before fermenting them?

Comment: What kind of beans are you asking about? At the moment there's not enough information to answer this.

Comment: @GdD Soy or pinto.

Comment: Fermenting them to produce what?

Comment: @FuzzyChef Mizo or tofu, for example

Comment: Wanna add that to your question?

Answer (score 3):

No.  Both tofu and miso require cooking the soybeans to work.

For miso, the soybeans [must be mashed into a paste](https://food52.com/blog/13601-make-miso-from-scratch-get-funky), which doesn't really work with raw soybeans.  Further, the koji culture grows on the starches and sugars present in cooked soybeans, not raw ones.  So creating a miso from raw soybeans would require you to obtain a different fungal culture designed for them, and the result probably wouldn't be miso.

Tofu is made through soymilk, which [must then be boiled](https://ohmyveggies.com/how-to-make-your-own-tofu/) to make it coagulate.  So while the soymilk itself is made with raw soybeans, if you don't boil it, you don't get tofu, just thickened soymilk.

Also note that raw soybeans [are poisonous](https://healthyeating.sfgate.com/happens-eat-raw-soybeans-11856.html), so in addition to producing a product, you'd have to be sure that any fermentation process you cultivated would successfully breakdown all lectins and protease inhibitors in the beans.  While fermentation is known to break down the saponins, the other two unhealthful chemicals usually require heat.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.culturesforhealth.com/:

> ...beans must be cooked before they can be eaten. They are very tough,
> and need rehydrating, and the cooking process further breaks down
> those hard-to-digest starches and anti-nutrients.
>
> So even if those beans ferment while soaking, you will still have to
> cook them in order to make them edible. That cooking process will
> eliminate any beneficial enzymes or probiotics that have been added to
> the beans through the fermentation process.

Comment: Can fermentation have the same effect on beans as cooking?

Comment: No @Geremia, fermenting doesn't have the same effect as cooking, fermenting doesn't break down the starches, fermented dried beans are still inedible.

Comment: @GdD Why wouldn't fermenting break down the starches? Starches are long strands of sugar, and fermentation feeds off sugars.

Comment: Feeds off yes,@Geremia, but it doesn't make them available.